# Flutter webview embed URL with access token and return URL

Tags: flutter, webview

I want to embed a webview in Flutter app with the URL like this:

```
'DOMAIN_NAME/vi/auth/login?access_token=TOKEN&return_url=RETURN_URL'
```

The token in the URL is used to verify the request, if token is verified, webview direct to the RETURN_URL. I've tried serveral webview plugin, they all stop at LoginScreen page.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the auth token using web-page's local storage, like following.

```
WebViewController _controller;

WebView(
          debuggingEnabled: true,
          initialUrl: _currentURL,
          onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
            _controller = controller;
            return _controller;
          },
          navigationDelegate: (navigation) async {
            
          },
          onPageFinished: (url) {
            
          },
          onWebResourceError: (error) {
            NavigationUtils(context).popCurrentPage();
          },
          onPageStarted: (url) {
            _controller.evaluateJavascript(
                "(function setData() { try { window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', '$TOKEN');} catch (error) { return error; }})();");
          },
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
```

Comment: No bro, I already have toke and want to send token to URL like above

Comment: you can provide _currentURL as _currentURL =
        'DOMAIN_NAME/vi/auth/login?access_token=TOKEN&return_url=RETURN_URL';

Comment: any solution ? I have similar situation. I have url with access_token as param exactly in yur case. If I hit it in desktop browser it works. but if I give it in initialURLRequest in webview it fails  . do yu have any suggestion @DalesVu

Answer (score 0):

in your android menifest file add

```
    <application
....
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
....>
```